# Updating metadata without deleting the previous value

Tags: wordpress

In the metadata field of the post I plan to record the ID of users who clicked the button. Each time you press the button, the previous user ID is erased. But it is necessary that the IDs of all users are recorded in the metadata field as an array.

Comment: So, what is the question?

Comment: Question is how add next ID without erase previous. Now after every update in metafield saved last user ID, need save all ID's as Array. Example: user click button "Vote" and update metafield with user ID, next user click button and update metafield with user ID. All ID's in one field saved. When I try use add_meta_field have multiple similar fields but when voted 100-200 users is a bad way. Need save all ID's in one field and get as Array.

Comment: Check this https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/243238/how-to-update-post-meta-value-as-array